# Promise reject not working inside of callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, callback, promise

I'm writing a module that uses the Google API, but am wrapping everything that is callback based in a promise. This is the code of the problem area

file1.js

```
var File2 = require('file2')
var api = new File2()
api.auth().then(auth => {
  api.search('example').then(res => {
     ...do some stuff...
  })
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('1') //Not being run
  throw err
})
```

file2.js

```
class File2(){
  auth() {
    ...works fine and resolves...
  }

  search() {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       googleapi.somemethod(options, (err, res) => {
         if(err) { 
           console.log('2') // DOES run
           reject(new Error(err))
         }
         resolve(res.field) //Program crashes here because reject didn't actually reject
       })
     })

}
```

The call to `auth` is working just fine, but the call to `search` (and more specifically `googleapi.somemethod`) is failing, and `err` is defined. I check for err, and `console.log('2')` runs, but then `console.log('1')` in `catch` doesn't run, the error isn't thrown, and the program crashed on `resolve(res)` because `res` is undefined. I've tried putting the error catcher as the second argument to `then` instead of using `catch`, but that still doesn't work

```
api.search('example').then(res => {
  ...do some stuff...
 }, err => {
    console.log('2') // Still doesn't run
    throw err
 })
```

I'm running Node v6.2.1

Comment: Shouldn't you `return` the promise? Also shouldn't there be an `else`? It looks like `resolve` will always be called regardless...

Comment: Am I not returning the promise? I've never seen someone do anything like 
> return resolve()
or
>return reject()

And as for the else, you might be right. I'm following the common pattern of handling callbacks that return something, but yeah this might not work for promises. I've always had it in my head though that "resolve" and "reject" sort of act like a return, but that may just be a hole in my knowledge of promises.

Comment: Check my answer, hope that helps. Also, nevermind about the `else` part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should return the promise:

```
var File2 = require('file2')
var api = new File2()
api.auth().then(auth => {
  return api.search('example').then(res => { // return the promise
     return ...
  })
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('1') // Not being run
  throw err
})
```

Also, if you don't need `auth` inside `search` then you can unnest those promises:

```
var File2 = require('file2')
var api = new File2()
api.auth().then(auth => {
  return api.search('example')
}).then(res => {
   return ...
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('1') //Not being run
  throw err
})
```

Comment: After doing what you said, my `console.log` inside of `catch` is running, but `throw err` isn't crashing the program. Any idea why that'd be?

Comment: `throw` shouldn't crash your program inside a promise, that's by design. Inside a promise `throw err === return Promise.reject(err)`, so you'd handle the error at a later `.catch()`, like `.catch(err => throw err).catch(handleError)`

Comment: Wouldn't `throw err === return Promise.reject(err)` in that second `.catch()` as well?

Comment: Yes, those are always equivalent, when you `throw` you have to `catch`, that's the point of promises, it mirrors the synchronous behavior. Read this post it'll clarify your doubts https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/.

Answer (score 5):

calling reject() does not stop your program, all codes below will be executed too.

Please update from

```
if(err) { 
  console.log('2') // DOES run
  reject(new Error(err))
}
resolve(res.field) //Program crashes here because reject didn't actually reject
```

to

```
if(err) { 
  console.log('2') // DOES run
  reject(new Error(err))
}
else {
  resolve(res.field) //Program crashes here because reject didn't actually reject
}
```

*** update ***
or you can shorten your code to

```
if(err) { 
  console.log('2') // DOES run
  return reject(err) // no need to new Error object
}
resolve(res.field) //Program crashes here because reject didn't actually reject
```

Comment: I thought about this too, but it is not the case because a promise can only be in one state. If it rejects then it cannot resolve. I would still write it with the `else` though because it makes the flow clearer.

Comment: or you can follow the 2nd solution that i update above @elclanrs

Comment: Yes, that's another option to make it clearer, but the point still stands, once you reject the resolve won't be called. See https://jsfiddle.net/g8yufxfa/